# Android: Writing to a file in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, writetofile

I would love to be able to write to a local directory in my AsyncTask subclass, but I can't seem to figure out how to use getFilesDir(), since I cannot, to my knowledge, create an instance of ContextWrapper and Context in this subclass.

So, what have I tried? I've tried getting the files directory the only way I know how by attempting many different things to create instances of Context and ContextWrapper in order to access the getFilesDir() method. That's it. That's all I know how to do.

I'm probably missing a lot of blatantly obvious things, but I've been working with Android for about 2 days now, so I still don't know how to debug my issues properly.

Any "ExplainLikeImFive" help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

From what I know now, you can only get the files directory through an Activity. Why is that?

Comment: I typed *"android write file in async task"* into Google and the first hit was an example that looks to me like it's what you're after.

Comment: @Madbreaks .. I'm quite embarrassed. I tried googling for a good 30-60 minutes.. Well, thank you! Let me see if it works!

Comment: @Madbreaks Oh. He was extending an Activity. Why can it only be done through an Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Context` object to access files in the local directory.  You can use an instance of an `Activity` as your `Context` object.  create an `AsyncTask` and give it a reference to your `Activity`.  Then in your `AsyncTask`, you can use the `Activity` to access the filesystem:

```
activity.getFilesDir();
```