# How to write to a file in the internal storage with an asynctask in a service?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I can't use the getFilesDir() in an asynctask which is in a service.
I saw this post:
[Android: Writing to a file in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204980/android-writing-to-a-file-in-asynctask)
It solves the problem in an activity but i dont find a way to do this in a service.
How to write to an internal storage file with an asynctask in a service?
This is my code in the asynctask:

```
  File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/IP.txt");
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at my answer?

Comment: Yes but it is not doing anything in my asynctask

Comment: Can you elaborate? How this can't be useful in AsyncTask? If you have object which pointing to directory, can't you use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Service` and `Activity` extend from `ContextWrapper` as well, so it has `getFilesDir()` method. Passing an instance of Service to `AsyncTask` object will solve it.

Something like:

```
File file = new File(myContextRef.getFilesDir() + "/IP.txt");
```

When you're creating the AsyncTask pass a reference of current Service (I suppose you're creating the `AsyncTaskObject` from Service):

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    protected void useFileAsyncTask() {
        FileWorkerAsyncTask task = new FileWorkerAsyncTask(this);
        task.execute();
    }

    private static class FileWorkerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Service myContextRef;

        public FileWorkerAsyncTask(Service myContextRef) {
            this.myContextRef = myContextRef;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            File file = new File(myContextRef.getFilesDir() + "/IP.txt");
            // use it ...
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont find a way to make `myContextRef` work. What do i have to write to the service?

Comment: nothing :) ... you just need to pass a reference to target `AsyncTask`. I'll update that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you start your service, you should pass String path which `getFileDir()` provides as follow.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,YourService.class); 
serviceIntent.putExtra("fileDir", getFileDir());
```

In your service in `onStart` method,

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
if(extras == null)
    Log.d("Service","null");
else
{
    Log.d("Service","not null");
    String fileDir = (String) extras.get("fileDir");
}
```