# ANR dialog box on certain input

Tags: android, button, android-anr-dialog

I am dynamically creating a table, and saving it in a file in the same activity. the time table is created based on user input.

**EDIT:-**
This is my class where i am generating a Dynamic layout for timetable.

```
public class CreateTimeTable extends Activity {

public static String[] tokens= new String[100];
public static int a,b;
Context con=this;
public int m,n,prod;
public final static String SAVETT="SAVETT.txt";
public static String str1="null";
public static String str2="\t";
public static String message="abc";
public static String message2="abc";
public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="abc";
public static String str3="\n";
DatabaseHandler db =new DatabaseHandler(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_time_table);
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    message = intent.getStringExtra(NewTT.EXTRA_MESSAGE);    //day
    message2 = intent.getStringExtra(NewTT.INPUT_SERVICE);   //lec
    int lec = Integer.parseInt(message2);
    int day =  Integer.parseInt(message);
    Button bt = new Button(this);
    a=lec; b=day;
    m =lec+1;
    n =day+1;
    prod=m*n;

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    TableLayout ll=new TableLayout(this);
    HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    int t=0;
    if(day==1) 
       {for(int i=-1;i<=lec;i++) 
         {  TableRow trow=new TableRow(this);
             if(i==-1)
                {   EditText tv1=new EditText(this);
                    EditText tv2=new EditText(this);
                    tv1.setText("  TIME  ");
                    tv1.setId(t);
                    tv1.setEnabled(false); 
                    tv1.setFocusable(false);
                    t++;
                    tv1.setTextSize(30);
                    tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                    trow.addView(tv1);
                    tv2.setText("  MONDAY  ");
                    tv2.setTextSize(30);
                    tv2.setId(t);
                    tv2.setEnabled(false); 
                    tv2.setFocusable(false);
                    t++;
                    tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                    trow.addView(tv2);
                 }

             else if (i==lec)
             {

                 bt.setText("SAVE");
                 bt.setTextSize(30);
                 trow.addView(bt);

             }

             else 
                {EditText e1=new EditText(this);
                  e1.setId(t);
                  e1.setTextSize(30);
                  t++;
                  e1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                  trow.addView(e1);
                  EditText e2=new EditText(this);
                  e2.setId(t);
                  t++;
                  e2.setTextSize(30);
                  e2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                  trow.addView(e2);                   
               }


            ll.addView(trow);
            View v = new View(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            ll.addView(v);
        }
       }


           // Similar 6 cases

   }


    hsv.addView(ll);
    sv.addView(hsv);
    sv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackboard);
    setContentView(sv);

        // Button that calls asynctask to save file

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {   public void onClick(View view) 
        {  

             SaveFile sf = new SaveFile();
             sf.execute(new String[] {"SAVETT.txt"});


         Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
         k.addFlags(k.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(k);

        }
    }); }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_time_table, menu);
    return true;
}

private class SaveFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    protected String doInBackground(String... name) 
        {  String inputString ="abc";
            System.out.println("Inside AsyncTask/n File Name is" + name[0]);
             int i=0;
             int t=0;
             try
             { FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(name[0],Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                while(prod>0)
                    {    if(t%n==0)
                            {           
                                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(t);
                                str1= editText.getText().toString();
                                fos.write(str1.getBytes());
                                fos.write("\t".getBytes());
                                t++;
                            }   
                        else
                        {           
                                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(t);
                                str1= editText.getText().toString();
                                fos.write(str1.getBytes());
                                fos.write("\t".getBytes());
                                t++;
                        }           
                        prod--;
                    }   
                fos.close();

                BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(name[0])));
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
                while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
                    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString);
                    int count = tokenizer.countTokens();
                    String[] arr = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
                    while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        arr[i]= tokenizer.nextToken();
                        i++;
                    }

                    i=0;
                    while(i<count)
                    {   System.out.println(arr[i]+"\n");
                        tokens[i]=arr[i];
                        i++;

                    } 
                }
        }

             catch( IOException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }



                return null;
           }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {

                  System.out.println("Starting Service " + a + b);
                  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service_Notification.class);
                  intent.putExtra("DAYS",b);

                  int requestCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                  PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, 0);
                  AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  // Start every 60 seconds
                  alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60*1000, pintent); 

                     ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), BootReciever.class);
                      PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

                      pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                              PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                              PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);



            }

    }

}
```

when i click on the save button a file is created and contents are saved. Now since i am using a Asynctask , the file is created perfectly. But the problem starts when i start a service in the  onPostExecute the program shows a loop of logcat errors as follows:

```
 03-17 04:15:51.605: W/System.err(3730):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-17 04:15:51.605: W/System.err(3730):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  03-17 04:15:51.605: W/System.err(3730):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-17 04:15:51.616: W/System.err(3730):   at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 03-17 04:15:51.616: W/System.err(3730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 03-17 04:15:51.625: W/System.err(3730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 03-17 04:15:51.625: W/System.err(3730):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 03-17 04:15:51.635: W/System.err(3730): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "d" (at offset 0)
 03-17 04:15:51.635: W/System.err(3730):    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
  03-17 04:15:51.645: W/System.err(3730):   at com.example.eduhub.Service_Notification.onStartCommand(Service_Notification.java:98)
  03-17 04:15:51.645: W/System.err(3730):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2704)
  03-17 04:15:51.645: W/System.err(3730):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-17 04:15:51.655: W/System.err(3730):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
03-17 04:15:51.655: W/System.err(3730):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 04:15:51.655: W/System.err(3730):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 04:15:51.655: W/System.err(3730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-17 04:15:51.655: W/System.err(3730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 04:15:51.655: W/System.err(3730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-17 04:15:51.655: W/System.err(3730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$Meth
```

My service Class is as Follows:

```
public class Service_Notification extends Service
  {   boolean i = true;
      Context c = this;

CreateTimeTable obj = new CreateTimeTable();

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful 


    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) 
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    String inputString;
    String[] alarm= new String[100];
    int days = obj.b;
    int lecs = obj.a;

    System.out.println(" A is " + lecs + "B is "+ days);


    int time;
    int i=lecs,k=0;
    long minutes;
    long hours;

    File name = new File(getFilesDir()+"/SAVETT.txt");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
    long hour=calendar.get(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    long min=calendar.get(calendar.MINUTE);

    try{

    if(name.exists())
    {
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            openFileInput("SAVETT.txt")));
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
    while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
           stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
           StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString);
           int count = tokenizer.countTokens();
           String[] arr = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
           while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
           {
              arr[k]= tokenizer.nextToken();
              k++;
           }

           k=0;
           while(k<count)
           { System.out.println(arr[k]+"\n");
             alarm[k]=arr[k];
              k++;

           } 
      }     

 System.out.println("Days:"+ days );
 System.out.println("Lecs"+ lecs );
 if(days!=0 && lecs!=0)
 {
  switch (today) 
    {
        case 2:   time = days+1;
                                 while(i>0)
                                 {
                                   String str = alarm[time];
                                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                                    try {
                                        Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
                                        Calendar c2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                                        c2.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
                                        hours=c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
                                        minutes=c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
                                        System.out.println("TIME TABLE Hour:" + hours);
                                        System.out.println("TIME TABLE minutes:" + minutes);

                                        if(hours==hour && min==minutes)
                                        {
                                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Attendance.class);
                                            notificationIntent.putExtra("class",alarm[time+1]);
                                            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                                    0, notificationIntent,
                                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                                            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                                                        .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.Cal))
                                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                        .setContentTitle("You Have a Lecture !!")
                                                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                        //.addAction(R.drawable.cross,"Cancel", btPendingIntent)
                                                        //.addAction(R.drawable.attn,"Attend" ,pIn)
                                                        .setLights(0xff00ff00,1000 * 6,1000*6)
                                                        .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                                        .setContentText(alarm[time+1]);

                                            Notification n = builder.getNotification();
                                            nm.notify(0, n);        

                                        }
                                        i--;
                                        time=time+days;
                                       } 
                                    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                 }
                                    break;
        case 3:   time = days+1;
                                while(i>0)
                                {
                                    String str = alarm[time];
                                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                                    try {
                                        Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
                                        Calendar c2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                                        c2.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
                                        hours=c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
                                        minutes=c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
                                        System.out.println("TIME TABLE Hour:" + hours);
                                        System.out.println("TIME TABLE minutes:" + minutes);
                                        if(hours==hour && min==minutes)
                                        {   
                                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Attendance.class);
                                            notificationIntent.putExtra("class",alarm[time+2]);
                                            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                                    0, notificationIntent,
                                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                                            /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Record.class);
                                            in.putExtra("class",alarm[time+1]);
                                            PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, in,0);
                                            */
                                            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_books)
                                                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                                                        .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.Cal))
                                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                        .setContentTitle("You Have a Lecture !!")
                                                        //.addAction(R.drawable.cross, "Cancell", btPendingIntent)
                                                        //.addAction(R.drawable.attn,"Attending",pIn)
                                                        .setLights(0xff00ff00,1000 * 6,1000*6)
                                                        .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                                        .setContentText(alarm[time+2]);
                                            Notification n = builder.getNotification();
                                            nm.notify(0, n);        

                                        }
                                        i--;
                                        time=time+days;
                                       } 

                                    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                }
                                break;
        case 4: time = days+1;
                                while(i>0)
                                    {
                                        String str = alarm[time];
                                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                                        try {
                                                Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
                                                Calendar c2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                                                c2.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
                                                hours=c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
                                                minutes=c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                                                System.out.println("TIME TABLE Hour:" + hours);
                                                System.out.println("TIME TABLE minute:" + minutes);
                                                if(hours==hour && min==minutes)
                                                {               

                                                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Attendance.class);
                                                    notificationIntent.putExtra("class",alarm[time+3]);
                                                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                                            0, notificationIntent,
                                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                                                    /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Record.class);
                                                    in.putExtra("class",alarm[time+1]);
                                                    PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, in,0);*/
                                                                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_books)
                                                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                                                                .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.Cal))
                                                                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                .setContentTitle("You Have a Lecture !!")
                                                               // .addAction(R.drawable.cross, "Cancell", btPendingIntent)
                                                                //.addAction(R.drawable.attn,"Attending",pIn)
                                                                .setLights(0xff00ff00,1000 * 6,1000*6)
                                                                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                                                .setContentText(alarm[time+3]);
                                                    Notification n = builder.getNotification();
                                                    nm.notify(0, n);        

                                                }
                                                i--;
                                                time=time+days;
                                               } 
                                        catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                    }
                                    break;
        case 5:                         time = days+1;
                                    while(i>0)
                                    {
                                        String str = alarm[time];
                                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                                        try {
                                                Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
                                                Calendar c2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                                                c2.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
                                                hours=c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
                                                minutes=c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                                                System.out.println("TIME TABLE Hour:" + hours);
                                                System.out.println("TIME TABLE minute:" + minutes);
                                                if(hours==hour && min==minutes)
                                                {

                                                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Attendance.class);
                                                    notificationIntent.putExtra("class",alarm[time+4]);
                                                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                                            0, notificationIntent,
                                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                                                    /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Record.class);
                                                    in.putExtra("class",alarm[time+1]);
                                                    PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, in,0);
                                                    */
                                                    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_books)
                                                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                                                                .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.Cal))
                                                                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                .setContentTitle("You Have a Lecture !!")
                                                                //.addAction(R.drawable.cross, "Cancell", btPendingIntent)
                                                                //.addAction(R.drawable.attn,"Attending",pIn)
                                                                .setLights(0xff00ff00,1000 * 6,1000*6)
                                                                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                                                .setContentText(alarm[time+4]);
                                                    Notification n = builder.getNotification();
                                                    nm.notify(0, n);        

                                                }
                                                i--;
                                                time=days;
                                               } 
                                        catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                break;
        case 6:  time = days+1;
                                while(i>0)
                                {
                                    String str = alarm[time];
                                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                                    try {
                                        Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
                                        Calendar c2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                                        c2.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
                                        hours=c2.get(c2.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
                                        minutes=c2.get(c2.MINUTE);

                                        System.out.println("TIME TABLE Hour:" + hours);
                                        System.out.println("TIME TABLE minute:" + minutes);
                                        if(hours==hour && min==minutes)
                                            {


                                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Attendance.class);
                                            notificationIntent.putExtra("class",alarm[time+5]);
                                            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                                    0, notificationIntent,
                                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);                                                                             builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_books)
                                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                                                .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.Cal))
                                                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                .setContentTitle("You Have a Lecture !!")
                                                //.addAction(R.drawable.cross, "Cancell", btPendingIntent)
                                                 //.addAction(R.drawable.attn,"Attending",pIn)
                                                 .setLights(0xff00ff00,1000 * 6,1000*6)
                                                 .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                                .setContentText(alarm[time+5]);
                                                Notification n = builder.getNotification();
                                                nm.notify(0, n);        

                                            }
                                            i--;
                                            time=time+days;
                                        } 
                                    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
        case 7:
                time = days+1;
                while(i>0)
                {
                    String str = alarm[time];
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                    try {
                            Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
                            Calendar c2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                            c2.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
                            hours=c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
                            minutes=c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            System.out.println("TIME TABLE Hour:" + hours);
                            System.out.println("TIME TABLE minute:" + minutes);if(hours==hour && min==minutes)
                            {


                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Attendance.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("class",alarm[time+6]);
                                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                        0, notificationIntent,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                                /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Record.class);
                                in.putExtra("class",alarm[time+1]);
                                PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, in,0);
                                */
                                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_books)
                                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                                            .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.Cal))
                                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                                            .setContentTitle("You Have a Lecture !!")
                                            //.addAction(R.drawable.cross, "Cancell", btPendingIntent)
                                              //          .addAction(R.drawable.attn,"Attending",pIn)
                                                        .setLights(0xff00ff00,1000 * 6,1000*6)
                                                        .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                                        .setContentText(alarm[time+6]);
                                Notification n = builder.getNotification();
                                nm.notify(0, n);        

                            }
                            i--;
                            time=time+days;
                           } 
                    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                                break;      

    }
 }

}   
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
  }
```

Cant figure out the problem. ;(  Please help

Answer (score 0):

ANR dialog appears when your application performs code on the application main thread (UI thread) which it execution taking unreasonable  amount of time.

unreasonable amount of time can be in some cases just a little more then a few milliseconds..

the `onClick` method, as any other `View` component callbacks - executed on the application main thread.

basically, you are doing [one of the few worst things can be done from main thread](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) - performing IO File operations!   and if that's not enough - your while loop might enter an endless loop if your `prod` parameter never rich the condition, or repeating itself potentially thousands of times.

you should perform IO file operations from a separate thread, using android API's allowing it [such `AsyncTask` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635724/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-the-internal-storage-with-an-asynctask-in-a-service).

second thing - check again what is the value of `prod` on run time. I don't know exactly what you tried to accomplish with this while loop, but it smells like trouble..

Comment: Ok.. So if i call a service and perform File I/O in that service would that make a difference?

Comment: @Ruchika: android's Service class callbacks also by default executes on the main thread, so if you want to be safe - also from there you'll have to perform such operations from a secondary thread using async task / worker thread  or any other way available to do that.

Comment: I have used an AsynTask for File I/O. But still my app displays an ANR dialog box. This time when i try to write something in the textviews.

Comment: @Ruchika: then you are probably doing it wrong (the IO should be executed from the doInBackground() callback)

Comment: Please View the Edited Question

Comment: @Ruchika: as I said, Service callbacks also executed on the main UI thread - your Service_Notification perform IO file operations from the onStartCommand() callbacks without performing it in async task.

Comment: @Ruchika: Sorry, but your code is terrible.. I don't have time to view and exam it today.   from what I see you are doing lot's of wrong things - loop inside loop that creates views and iterate them can also be problematic...

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the problem. thanks for your time.